# Form details to be displayed in the grid

Tags: sql-server, delphi, datagridview, tcxgrid

I have basic question from my side, as I am Beginner level in Delphi XE2.

I am using VCL form and entering the Form details in the edit box and to be displayed in the grid with several basic operation like Add, Delete and Update/Retrieve. Whereas the details have to be saved in the SQL server.

If I am using the form later on, i need the Previous data in the grid from the SQL. For those operation my Update/Retrieve field operation must be done on Delphi or SQL server.

Hope everyone would have come across these basic forms. So help me.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rajan.

Comment: please improve this question by adding code examples and a better description, as it is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Developing_Database_Applications

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Developing_Database_Applications_Index

Those are basic topics about making your application connecting to database.

---

ExpressQuantumGrid is very complex and expensive control on it's own, it does not have online help but does have offline one, and there is "Task-based help / Connecting to Data" section that covers what u need about that certain grid. Do you really use [tcxgrid](/questions/tagged/tcxgrid) component or just put that tag at random guess ? You say u have no Delphi experience but did you really purchase DevArt library which price may be almost as large as Delphi itself ? If you did you may try opening their [VCL demos](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/training-demos.xml) and reading their sources how they were implemented.